# what's the best expression for this wish sentence

Tags: word-usage

I want to write a christmas card and I'd like to know what sentence sounds better

- That in 2020 you can spend time with what is essential - friends, family,...
- That in 2020 you look at what is essential - friends, family...

Thanks!

Comment: We don't usually advise *how* to spend the next year, just that it will be good. It can be tactless to wish time spent with family, when the recipient has no immediate family, or to tell them what is essential, as it implies that you think they aren't spending enough time on that. **Best wishes for 2020**.

Comment: Thanks. I totally agree with you! I was asked to translate that - for a card - and I can't find sth that sounds good and it is still close to the original meaning. In my primary language I think it doesn't sound so tactless (or implying that the person is not spending enough time with...). It is more like "I hope you have plenty of time to spend with what is important/essential for you..."

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you eliminate "what is," which is wordy.  In writing, less is usually better.

*That in 2020 you can spend time with the essentials - friends, family...*

*That in 2020 you look at the essentials - friends, family...*

Comment: Please note that general style / writing advice is off-topic on ELU. There is another SE which deals with writing generally (as opposed to meaning of individual words, grammaticality ,...).

Comment: Sorry. Can you please tell me which one?

Comment: "Sounds better" is a style question, as Edwin points out, though I think "what is" is poor usage, which my answer addressed.  As to "which one," the sentences have different meanings, so "which sounds better" depends on which more accurately expresses your intent.